# I can't log into any Minecraft servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I try to log into any minecraft server (i'm in 1.10) it keeps saying 'logging in' and then eventually times out, or just stays on the log in screen. It has done this to the main server i'm on yesterday, and then I joined another yesterday, it was fine, but now I can't join that same server again. I joined another server, and now i'm afraid that will refuse me connection. What do i do?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you could try:

- Refreshing the server page
- Restarting your Minecraft
- Restarting your computer
- Turning your internet on and off again
- Turning your router off and on again
- Wait it out

Hope this helps!

-APthree